# If the onComplete call is made for a RxJava Subject, do i have to manually unsubscribe again?

Tags: android, rx-java

I'm using an [RxJava ReplaySubject](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Subject#replaysubject) in my Fragment.

I'm attempting to use the ReplaySubject in a way, where I would like the Subject to execute a process until completion (possibly beyond the life of the fragment).

On completion of the process, I would like to release the resources which -as i understand- is done by unsubscribing the subscription at the time of registering the observer (which in my case, is the subject itself).

In this [github issue thread](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/386) @benjchristensen says:

> If it is an Observable then it should emit an onCompleted and be done.
>
> If it is an Observer then it should unsubscribe from the Subscription it received when it called Observable.subscribe and it will give the Observable a chance to shutdown and clean up.

If it's a Subject -which is both an Observer and an Observable- what is the behavior? If i call onComplete on the subject, does that basically mean the subscription is stopped, and I am therefore relieved of needing to manually unsubscribe the subscription i get by registering the observer?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Subjects are a relatively thin layer on top of an Observable that allow you to feed `onNext()`, `onCompleted()` and `onError()` calls from a source external to the Observable. Their unsubscribe behavior is the same as an Observable. If `onCompleted()` or `onError()` are called on the Subject, the subscribers will be unsubscribed. No need to call `unsubscribe()` on the subscription returned from `Observable.subscribe()`.

For a `ReplaySubject`, note that resources will not be cleaned up until it is garbage collected. Even after `onCompleted()` has been called on a `ReplaySubject`, a subscriber can still subscribe and it will receive all of the original `onNext()`, `onCompleted()` or `onError()` calls that were made previous to subscribing.

Comment: Is this also true for .cache and .replay transformed  observables?

Comment: Is this mentioned in the documentation somewhere? I literally spent 1 hour on this today before I found this thread.

Comment: @DenissB. I don't remember seeing anything in the documentation. Personally, I don't rely on this behavior. I always save off my subscriptions and then unsubscribe since calling unsubscribe on an already unsubscribed subscription has no effect.

Comment: But what if I need to subscribe again? Subject is completed and I can't connect to it again (it is just return onComplete). Could you give me advise?